# There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported, but I'm using putmapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a full-stack application which contains a user, product, addon (toppings), and more.

However, when I try to run localhost:8080/Admin/users/Sean (example), it is supposed to promote the user. However, instead it simply gives me the above error. "Get not supported". This is happening despite the fact that I'm using putmapping, not getmapping.
Below is provided code.

**AdminController.java**

```
package com.example.pizza_order_service.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.pizza_order_service.model.Addon;
import com.example.pizza_order_service.model.Product;
import com.example.pizza_order_service.model.User;
import com.example.pizza_order_service.service.AddonService;
import com.example.pizza_order_service.service.ProductService;
import com.example.pizza_order_service.service.UserService;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService prodService;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AddonService addonService;
    
    @GetMapping("")
    public ModelAndView listProducts() {
        List<Product> products = prodService.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("product","Product", products);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView listAddons() {
        List<Addon> addons = addonService.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("product","Addon", addons);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/Product")
    public String displayProducts(ModelMap model) {
        Iterable<Product> results = prodService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("product", results);
        return "product";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/Toppings")
    public String displayToppings(ModelMap model) {
        Iterable<Addon> results = addonService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("toppings", results);
        return "Addon";
    }
    
    
    // - Promote Users
    
    @PutMapping("/users/{id}")
    public String promoteUser(User newUser){
          User user = userService.findUserByUserName(newUser.getName());
          user.setRole(newUser.getRole());
          return "Promotion confirmed";
        }
    
    
    //- Delete Product
    
    @DeleteMapping(value="/deleteProd/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteAProduct(@PathVariable("id") long id)  {  
        prodService.deleteProduct(id);
        return listProducts();
    }

    
    //- Delete Toppings
    
    @DeleteMapping(value="/deleteAddon/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteAnAddon(@PathVariable("id") long id)  {  
        addonService.deleteAddon(id);
        return listAddons();
    }

    
    
}
```

***users.html***

```
<!-- HTML -->
<html id="content">
    <head>
        <div th:replace="fragment.html :: header"></div>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <style>
            td {
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- End CSS -->
    </head>
    <body class="background" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div th:replace="fragment.html :: navbar"></div>

        <!-- Menu -->
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <table class="xy-center" style="position: fixed; background-color: var(--tertiary); color: var(--primary); font-size: 3.5vh; border-radius: 15px; padding: 5px;">
            <b th:utext="${user}"></b>
        </table>
        <!-- End Menu -->
        <p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        Hello World!</p>
        
    </body>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script>
        // To open the navbar buttons
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.first-button').on('click', function () {
                $('.animated-icon1').toggleClass('open');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- End JS -->
</html>
```

If more code is needed please let me know, it is a fairly large application. Thank you.

Edit: By the way, I get the same error when I try to invoke the DeleteMappings as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "I try to run localhost:8080/Admin/users/Sean"?

Comment: That’s what I typed in the browser in response to the first commenter

Comment: Then you should instead run a `curl -X PUT`. When typing an URL in your browser, it does run a `GET` method by default. You can edit the method in the `Network` tab of the inspector, right click and edit the request. Still, I recommend using `curl` or any other testing tools (Postman if you prefer GUI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't run PUT commands if you just type in the address as the url. You'll need to use an HTTP client such as cURL or Postman

Comment: I see, does the same go for the deletemappings?

Comment: Of course, your web browser is an HTTP client, but in order to run other methods than `GET`, it needs to get specifically instructed to: using a `form` with `method` attribute defined (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form).

Comment: When I try it in postman I just get redirected to a different page, even though I added the url to the WebSecurityConfig (hopefully correctly)

Comment: Would be nice to have a `curl` to help you out. You should better open a new issue since this one is solved.

Comment: @Vincent HTML form methods don't support put (or delete), though

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should try `/api/v1/` in front of your path meaning
`localhost:8080/Admin/users/Sean` will become `localhost:8080/api/v1/Admin/users/Sean`. Could you please try that ?

Comment: That doesn't change the HTTP method and largely depends on the spring properties if the path is needed

Comment: What makes you believe there is a `/api/v1/` context path given provided information?

Comment: I tried adding that to the WebSecurityConfig page but I still get a redirect when typing that example you gave into the browser

Answer (score 0):

You request will not be answered by

```
@PutMapping("/users/{id}")
```

as it will only accept PUTs.

You need another endpoint for returning the html page (via the browsers GET request), like

```
 @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
 public ModelAndView showUserPage(User user){
     return new ModelAndView("users","User", user);
 }
```

Comment: Based on the question, they actually want to run a PUT